# How do I rotate an object by theta and phi?

Tags: python, scripting, mathematics, conversion

I am trying to translate theta and phi rotation in Blender to the Euler XYZ rotation about each axis. To do this I am currently using the following code:
"""

```
 def Sphere2Euclid(theta, phi):
    """
    Inputs: theta - Angle as defined in the GA
            phi - Angle as defined in the GA

    Outputs: x - The x rotation angle in Euler Angle Coordinates
             y - The y rotation angle in Euler Angle Coordinates
             z - The z rotation angle in Euler Angle Coordinates

    Description: This function will take the theta and phi angles as defined in the GA and convert them to Euler Coordinates

    Source for conversion: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158377/object-rotation-with-polar-angles-python 
    """

x = math.sin(math.radians(theta)) * math.cos(math.radians(phi)) 
y = math.sin(math.radians(theta)) * math.sin(math.radians(phi))
z = math.cos(math.radians(phi))
return x, y, z
```

This current code doesn't seem to rotation from a global orientation as it does not produce the correct orientation for testing angles. Is my method of converting from theta and phi to XYZ wrong or am I fundamentally misunderstanding how blender handles rotation?

Comment: it should be `z = math.cos(math.radians(theta))` i tested and it's correct.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. Your *z* calculation was incorrect. It should be angle $\theta\space(theta)$ instead of $\phi\space(phi)$:

```
z = math.cos(math.radians(theta))
```

Also take note you are also missing the radius, but I assume it is just a unit sphere ($r=1$) so I guess it's not a problem if excluded.

To visualize the [Spherical Coordinate System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system), here is a drawing I made where:
$$v=\theta \space (theta)$$
$$u=\phi \space (phi)$$
[image]

This results in:

$$x=r\sin \theta \cos \phi $$
$$y=r\sin \theta \sin \phi $$
$$z=r\cos \theta$$

I made an example where $\theta=67.5$ and $\phi=33.75$ on a unit sphere ($r=1$)

[image]

After executing the script and checking the console I can see that the vertex location on the euclidean plane has been calculated correctly.

[image]

Working script here with example:

```
import bpy
import math

def Sphere2Euclid(theta, phi):
    """
    Inputs: theta - Angle as defined in the GA
            phi - Angle as defined in the GA

    Outputs: x - The x rotation angle in Euler Angle Coordinates
             y - The y rotation angle in Euler Angle Coordinates
             z - The z rotation angle in Euler Angle Coordinates

    Description: This function will take the theta and phi angles as defined in the GA and convert them to Euler Coordinates

    Source for conversion: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158377/object-rotation-with-polar-angles-python 
    """

    x = math.sin(math.radians(theta)) * math.cos(math.radians(phi)) 
    y = math.sin(math.radians(theta)) * math.sin(math.radians(phi))
    z = math.cos(math.radians(theta))
    
    return x, y, z

coords = Sphere2Euclid(67.5, 33.75)

print(coords)
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for the detailed answer on this. My issue is more that I need to take theta and phi rotation angles and translate them to rotations around the x,y,z axis (the Euler angles). This seems to be coordinates, which isn't what I want as I just need to rotate the object by theta and phi. 
Am I overthinking this and translating theta and phi to it's respective rotations about the x,y,z axis is straight forward? 
I will also add, the reason phi is due to using physics notation, not math (it's annoying but in physics we flipped them for some reason.. luckily it's a non-issue)

Comment: @Jacob hmm u should probably edit the content of your thread as it is not clear to me what you are asking for. maybe include a drawing or screenshot of what exactly u are trying to solve.